# Changing background image setinterval only calling once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is in REACT.JS.  I have combed through the different posts on here trying to find a solution, however I have not been able to get this to run more than once.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!  I have the component code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Login.css'
import LoginHousing from './LoginHousing'
import bg1 from '../../images/backgrounds/lawn-maintenance.jpg'
import bg2 from '../../images/backgrounds/body-shop.jpg'
import bg3 from '../../images/backgrounds/mechanic.jpg'
import bg4 from '../../images/backgrounds/painting.jpg'
import bg5 from '../../images/backgrounds/hair-stylist.jpg'

export default class Login extends Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {loginBg: bg1}
}

// Background slideshow effect on mount, changing every 2 seconds
changingBackground() {
    let i = 0
    const images = [bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, bg5]

    if (i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }

    this.setState({loginBg: images[i]})
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(
        () => this.changingBackground(),
        2000
    );
}

componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.timer)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='login vw-100 vh-100' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.loginBg})`}}>
            <LoginHousing />
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: `if (i < images.length) {` check is going to give you a broken image

Comment: @epscarello I did not see that, fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately that throws a: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let i = 0
```

This variable is *local* to the function, so each time that function is executed in the interval, you basically start *from the beginning*.

---

You could change code to this:

```
changingBackground() {       
    this.setState((ps) => {
      return {
        index: (ps.index + 1) % this.images.length, // store images in instance field
      };
    });
  }
```

And then render:

```
this.images[this.state.index]
```

PS and constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { index: 0 };
}
```

Comment: I will check into that now, give me just a moment

Comment: I am at work at the moment, I will try this out as soon as I can!

Comment: Thanks that got it working!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a little explanation before the solution for this, because when you are calling the `this.changingBackground()` it will always get to **zero** again, as you see in the first declaration of the `let i = 0` so each time that function runs it will be zero, I think the best solution for this is making the **counter** for the background-images a **state** variable:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {loginBg: bg1, indexImage: 0}
  }

  changingBackground() {
      const images = [bg1, bg2, bg3, bg4, bg5]

      if (indexImage < images.length - 1) {
          this.setState({indexImage: this.state.indexImage + 1});
      } else {
          this.setState({indexImage: 0});
      }

      this.setState({loginBg: images[this.state.indexImage]});
  }


  componentDidMount() {
      this.timer = setInterval(
          () => this.changingBackground(),
          2000
      );
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
      clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too Wesler, I utilized some of both of your answers to come up with a great solution!

Comment: Thanks man, always here to help!